# How can I set a global variable from a script/command line?

Tags: variables, vim, tabs, global-variables

I'm trying to create a little menu to switch from "YouCompleteMe" to "Supertab" and vice versa.

```
function! TabFunction()
 if !exists("g:WhatTab")
   let g:WhatTab = "Tab function?"
 endif
 if !exists("g:MenuTab_choices")
   let g:MenuTab_choices = "&SuperTab\n&YouCompleteMe"
 endif
 let n = confirm(g:WhatTab, g:MenuTab_choices, "Question")

 if n == 1
   let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<Tab>'
   let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<S-Tab>'

   let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-Tab>', '<Down>']
   let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-S-Tab>', '<Up>'] 
 elseif n == 2
   let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<C-Tab>'
   let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<C-S-Tab>'

   let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<Tab>', '<Down>']
   let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<S-Tab>', '<Up>']   
 endif
endfun
```

This doesn't work.
When I try to check the value of these variables from the commandline
`:echo 'global variable'`
the values are correct but they don't work as expected.

Is it not possible to declare a global variable like this?

Comment: That should work (as far as setting global variables from functions).

Answer (score 4):

The use of the `g:` variable prefix ensures that the global variables are set from within a function; this is correct. Your problem is that the **plugin configuration variables** like `g:SuperTabMappingForward` **are only evaluated once during plugin load** (when Vim starts up), but not during runtime. This mechanism wasn't meant for dynamic reconfiguration.

#### Solutions

Instead of toggling the (ignored) config variables, you have to do the remapping yourself. At least SuperTab defines corresponding `<Plug>...` targets; I guess YCM does this, too:

```
if n == 1
  imap <Tab> <Plug>SuperTabForward
  ...
elseif n == 2
  imap <C-Tab> <Plug>SuperTabForward
```

Alternatively, the brute-force variant would be to reload the plugins (`:runtime plugin/supertab.vim`) to get the changed global variable values to be considered, but that's very inefficient, may cause errors, and makes you work around plugin load guards in addition.

Comment: Thank you Ingo. Youcompleteme does the mapping like this `exe 'inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab> "'` When I use this in `n==2` it partially works: Sometimes when I use the <TAB> key youcompleteme suggestions comes up, but sometimes also SuperTab suggestions. It seems as the <TAB> is still in use with SuperTab.

Comment: Where's the plugin trigger in that mapping? Something's still missing from the picture...

Comment: There is no plugin trigger in the two youcompleteme.vim files in the bundle map (one youcompleteme.vim in autoload, one youcompleteme.vim in the plugin map)

Comment: So does YCM just rely on `'completefunc'` or `'omnifunc'`? Then you wouldn't need to switch SuperTab mappings at all, but configure the completion source instead!

Comment: Don't understand you very well. Is this the YCM completefunc mapping? `command! -nargs=* -complete=custom,youcompleteme#SubCommandsComplete
  \ YcmCompleter call s:CompleterCommand(<f-args>)`

Comment: I just checked the plugin (not using it); it depends on `CursorMovedI` events to automatically put up the matches. (The docs also mention that it can do everything that SuperTab does.) I'm not at all sure it can be toggled; you may want to ask on YCM's issue tracker for advice. Sorry, that's all I can offer. That plugin is a huge monster, with client-server architecture and all.